# SQL Server : duplicate rows while changing a columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T, say

```
1 | a
2 | a
```

I want to duplicate its rows while changing the value of the second column to b, so as to have

```
1 | a
2 | a
1 | b
2 | b
```

I came to

```
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) 
   SELECT col1, 'b' 
   FROM T
```

but I get an error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: What if `T` contains other values, say `3-c`,`4-d`?

Comment: what subquery? you haven't provided the complete query to assess, there has to be some "subquery" probably a select contained inside the select clause e.g. `select x, (select max(y) from a ...) from`

Comment: Nothing wrong with your example, that works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f8ce/1. Please show the actual code or a better example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: yes, I confirmed it also, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b73bc/2 in trying to simplify your real query for this question you have taken out the parts that matter

Comment: I think you've edited out the issue from the question, so as it stands it has no value, you should roll it back to the state where the issue was present.

Comment: indeed, I omitted the faulty part of my query. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those extra parentheses in the SELECT :

```
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, 'b' AS col2 FROM T;
```

Comment: Is your table definition complete in your question or does it have more rows or columns into it ?

Comment: Something is missing in your question. See this sqlfiddle, it actually works : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/683d7/1

Comment: the table has 2 columns and around 50 entries. I would like to duplicate some of the entries and change a column's value in the duplicated entries

Comment: indeed, I omitted the faulty part of my query. Thanks anyways